# How to search for a name field contains utf8 characters in django REST?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, utf-8

I have 2 models `Watch` and `Product`. A `Product` can have multiple `Watch`. The code for 2 models like below

```
class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Watch(models.Model):
    ACTIVE = 1
    DEACTIVATE = 2
    FINISH = 3
    STATUS_CHOICES = [(ACTIVE, 'Active'), (DEACTIVATE,
                                           'Deactivate'), (FINISH, 'Finish')]
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        related_name='watches',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=2, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=ACTIVE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I'm implementing a searching feature to get the list of watches based on the name of the product. Currently, like so

```
class WatchList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = WatchSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    name = 'watch-list'
    filter_fields = ('status', 'owner')
    search_fields = ('^product__name',)
    ordering_fields = ('-updated_at')
    ordering = ('-updated_at')
```

But when I try to call the API and search with a string contains utf8 characters (the string is **nồi chiên không dầu**), I got nothing back. I try a search pattern with only **n** character. Then it works. So I think the problem is utf8 in my first search pattern.

How do I solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. It isn't because of utf8 characters. I need to remove the `^` character in the `search_fields` attribute (don't know why) and encode the name of the product before pass it to the url.

It so fantastic if anyone can explain why the search function doesn't work with the `^` character. Thank you guys